# ¿Cual es la forma correcta de usar el operador ## en las macros de ensamblador de Z80 Pasmo?

Tags: macros, ensamblador, asm

Estoy intentado incluir un bucle dentro de un REPT en Pasmo. Pongo un ejemplo sencillo:

```
REPT 10,Iter
   ld b,20
   ld a,Iter
   bucle:
     sub 1
   djnz bucle
ENDM
```

Obviamente me da error al duplicar la etiqueta bucle.
He leído que el operador ## se puede usar para solventar este problema, pero no encuentro la sintaxis correcta para usarlo.